# Importing class from another file - where to put 'import' statements that the class requires

Tags: python, class, python-import

I have two Python files, one named `main.py` and one named `second.py`. A class exists in `second.py` that uses a couple of modules.

Am I able to instantiate the class from code running in `main.py`, therefore allowing me to import the modules in `main.py`? Or do I have to actually have the modules imported in `second.py`, where the class exists?

I ask this as I thought it would be logical that, if you're instantiating a class into an object with code in `main.py`, then the functions within this class object should be able to use the modules imported at the start of `main.py`. So, typically, where would the `import module` statements go? `main.py` or `second.py.`

Comment: You should `import` the modules that the class needs *where the class is defined*, i.e. in `second.py`. If those modules are *also* needed by other classes/functions in `main.py`, `import` them there too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe 
So the class object within main.py still uses the modules imported in second.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple counter-example: what if you rely on a module in `second.py` that is only imported in `main.py`?

**`main.py`**:

```
import time

import second

timer = second.Timer()

print timer.timestamp()
```

**`second.py`**:

```
class Timer(object):

    def timestamp(self):
        return time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

**Outcome**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jonrsharpe/Documents/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    print timer.timestamp()
  File "/Users/jonrsharpe/Documents/second.py", line 4, in timestamp
    return time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
NameError: global name 'time' is not defined
```

The classes and functions defined in `file.py` *use the scope defined within that file* - any `import`s that they require to work must be made in `file.py`. Otherwise, you would be relying on the module that imports `file.py` to also import whatever else `file.py` needs to work, which would be ridiculous.

Comment: But isn't your counter-example simply calling the function located in second.py? My confusion lies within the concept of instantiating the class. If the object is created in main.py does it change namespace to that of main.py or does it stay within second.py? If that makes any sense :-/

Comment: *"simply calling the function"* - as opposed to what? Why should classes and functions behave differently? I have switched to a class example, which (surprise!) does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Don't misconstrue my questions or statements as criticisms, I'm trying to understand the difference. I thought calling a function would execute that function with any passed arguments within second.py and instantiating a class would bring the instance to main.py but I guess i'll just have to run with the understanding that the class instance uses second.py's imported modules (as your example proves) no matter where it's instantiated. Cheers.